# How to write text to a file that contains a path?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I get an absolute path from an html document using

```
$('#id').attr('src')
```

When I try to save this src to a text file it saves as a string with only one slash like this

```
C:\path\path1\path2
```

I need it to save to my file like this

```
C:\\path\\path1\\path2
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Try using backslash ("/") or use path module in node.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `String.prototype.replace()` method for replacing one backslash by two backslashes:

```js
var path = $('#id').attr('src').replace(/\\/g,"\\\\");
console.log(path);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="id" src="C:\path\path1\path2">
```

Answer (score 0):

Repalce `\` with `\\`

```
$('#id').attr('src').replace(/\\/g, '\\\\');
```